# My computer's dying :(

Tags: display, reboot

I have a sweet computer and have never had any real problems with it until now. I recently formatted my computer and all was well. But now my monitor randomly flickers. The monitor will just go black for about a second or two, then it'll return back to its normal state with all the stuff still on the screen. This is getting progressively worse.

Another problem that has started is my computer randomly restarts. (I've managed to prevent it from restarting by removing the check in Automatically Restart from the Startup and Recovery Dialog. But I know this doesn't solve the problem). It also completely freezes up on me.

One last thing, this morning I got a big blue screen. I can't remember what it said, but if it happens again I will take note of it and repost. Or if I can find some kind of a log file containing that bluescreen error I will post.

I have checked all cords, and they're all fine. Nothing's loose. My computer isn't overheating either. I've taken the case off for 3 whole days and haven't used the computer for those 3 days, which has had no effect.

I've checked the connections inside and nothing's loose there either. I know there's nothing wrong with my monitor because my friend has 2 computers and it works perfectly on those computers.

I don't understand how my computer could suddenly become so unstable. I'm almost certain that I have no viruses; I full-scan my pc everyday for nastys, and have strict firewall settings. Anyway, I don't see how it could be a virus anyway simply due to the fact that I had these problems right after I formatted, and before I even had the chance to install or copy anything or even connect to the internet.

I know it has nothing to do with the way I formatted the computer too, I've been fixing computers for years.

Sorry for rambling on, just making sure I don't leave anything out.

Has anybody else had this problem? Can somebody please try to help me with this?

Thank you :)

Comment: Sounds like either a faulty graphics card or psu.

Comment: Replace the graphics card.

Comment: :( Damn. I was hoping it wasn't the graphics card. They're so expensive over here lol. Thanks MrStatic & goblinbox! :)

Comment: Hmmm... Could it be the fact that maybe (just maybe) I forgot to install the drivers for my graphics card after I formatted?

Comment: Doubtful. But try it anyway before spending the money for a new one.

Comment: Oh, MrStatic; I've recently bought a new Power Supply Unit, about 4weeks ago. And that solved my problem of the computer not turning on at all. So I think it's the GFX  Card

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup, definitely the videocard. If the monitor is not the problem, the only other option is the videocard. That would explain the BSOD too.

Comment: lol I love the name they've given it (Blue Screen Of Death). Sounds like I'll have to go and get myself a new grahpics card :D

Comment: Sorry I can't upvote you because I don't have enough rep yet.

Comment: now you have enough rep.  welcome to superuser!